# Array_intersect and order of values returned

Tags: php

I'm fairly new to PHP and I have a question.

I'm trying to make a function that adds tags to a text.
My function works but the order of the tags in the array returned is wrong.

How can I change the order, please

Thanks for any help.

```
 <?php
    
     $tags = [
        'animals' => ['cat', 'dog', 'horse', 'ferret'],
        'nature' => ['walk', 'outdoor', 'tree', 'plant']];
        
        
        function getTags(string $text, array $tags): array
        {
            $lowerC = strtolower($text);
            $str = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z\'\- ]/", '', $lowerC);
            $arrayT = explode(" ", $str);
        
            $tagArray = [];
            foreach ($tags as $tag => $value) {
                
                    if (array_intersect( $value, $arrayT )) {
                        $tagArray[] = $tag;
                }
        
            }   return $tagArray;
          
        }
    
    
    $res = getTags('During my walk, I met a white horse', $tags);
    var_dump($res); // returns ['animals', 'nature'] but I'm trying to get ['nature', 'animals']
```

Comment: They are coming back out in the order they are in your tag array. If you want the order to be different change their order in `$tags`

Comment: Why do you expect if to return `nature` first, what is the logic (first encountered word, most words?)

Comment: Yes the first tag in the array must be 'nature' because the word 'walk' comes before 'horse'. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get 'nature' first, because 'walk' comes before 'horse', you need to iterate over the words first, not over the tags.

```
$tags = [
    'animals' => ['cat', 'dog', 'horse', 'ferret'],
    'nature' => ['walk', 'outdoor', 'tree', 'plant'],
];
    
    
function getTags(string $text, array $tags): array
{
    $lowerC = strtolower($text);
    $str = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z\'\- ]/", '', $lowerC);
    $arrayT = explode(" ", $str);

    $tagArray = [];
    foreach ($arrayT as $word) {
        // find tag for this word
        foreach ($tags as $cat => $values) {
            if (in_array($word, $values)) {
                // append the tag to the list
                $tagArray[] = $cat;
            }
        }
    }
    
    // remove duplicates
    return array_unique($tagArray);
  
}


$res = getTags('During my walk, I met a white horse', $tags);
var_dump($res);
```

Output :

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "nature"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "animals"
}
```

**EDIT**

As @GeorgeGarchagudashvili mentionned, the code could be optimized by preparing an array for comparison. Here is a way :

```
function getTags(string $text, array $tags): array
{
    $lowerC = strtolower($text);
    $str = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z\'\- ]/", '', $lowerC);
    $arrayT = explode(" ", $str);
    
    // Prepare tags for searching
    $searchTags = [];
    foreach ($tags as $cat => $values) {
        foreach ($values as $word) {
            $searchTags[$word] = $cat;
        }
    }

    $tagArray = [];
    foreach ($arrayT as $word) 
    {
        // find tag for this word
        if (isset($searchTags[$word])) 
        {
            // append the tag to the list
            $tagArray[] = $searchTags[$word];
        }
    }
    
    // remove duplicates
    return array_unique($tagArray);
  
}
```

Comment: You could optimize your code's runtime by preparing tags array for comparison and iterating words array after. N*M => N+M

Comment: Agree, I'll update the answer. Thank you @GeorgeGarchagudashvili